# Prefix expression evaluator in c using callback and nested lists

Tags: c, callback, linked-list, prefix

I must write a prefix evaluator in C using the structure below, but I have no idea how to do it using callback. My main doubts are how do I access the values after I have "built" the list and how do I assign a value to a pointer to function.

```
typedef struct node
{
    enum type_node type;
    union
    {
        int val;
        int (*func)(struct node *x);
        struct node *sublist;
    } info;
    struct no *next;
} node, *ptr_node;
```

Comment: This is two separate issues, each of which is searchable. [c linked-list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+linked-list) [c function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+function+pointer) After building the list, the head value will be `head->info.val` if `head->type` indicates a *value*-node, or `head->info.func` if `head->type` indicates a function value. The remainder of the list will be `head->next`, and subsequence `->next` pointers until the terminating NULL pointer. To assign a function pointer, just assign it: `head->info.func = myfunc`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is mostly nonsense code that doesn't actually do anything.
However, it will most likely compile, and shows methods to access the structure, and call a function using a function pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum type_node 
   {
   VALUE,
   FUNCTION,
   STRUCTURE
   };

typedef struct node
   {
   enum type_node type;
   union
      {
      int val;
      int (*func)(struct node *x);
      struct node *sublist;
      } info;
   struct node *next;
   } node, *ptr_node;   

int myfunc(struct node *someNode)
   {
   int rCode;

   printf("type: %d\n", someNode->type;
   switch(someNode->type)
      {
      case VALUE:
         printf("value: %d\n", someNode->info.val);
         break;

      case FUNCTION:
         rCode=(*someNode->info.func)(someNode);
         break;

      case STRUCTURE:
          printf("value: %d\n", someNode->info.val);
          printf("func: %p\n", someNode->info.func);
          printf("sublist: %p\n", someNode->sublist);
          printf("next: %p\n", someNode->next);
          break;
      };

   return(0);
   }


int main(void)
   {
   ptrNode np;
   int rCode;

   node n1 = 
      {
      .type = VALUE,
      .info.val  = 2,
      .next = NULL
      };

   node n2 =
      {
      .type = FUNCTION,
      .info.func = myfunc,
      .next = &n1 
      };


   node n3 =
      {
      .type = STRUCTURE,
      .info.sublist = &n2,
      .next = NULL
       };

   np = &n1;
   n1->next = &n3; 
   printf("np->type: %d\n", np->type);
   printf("n1.type: %d\n", n1.type);
   printf("n1.info.val: %d\n", n1.info.val);
   printf("np->info.val: %d\n", np->info.val);

   np = &n2;
   rCode=(*np->info.func)(np);
   rCode=(*n2.info.func)(np);


   return(0);
   }
```